# How to delete all the occurrence of `"` to convert the string in to int in a big file

Tags: string, replace, replaceall

I have a file with more than 100k rows and it contains data in the form of 
`"122345",` in each row but I need integer instead of string, what is the best method to do

Comment: What OS are you working on? Are you trying to remove every " or just some of them?

Comment: MacOS.
I am trying to remove all the occurrences of ". If I wanted to delete the some of them I must know about the positions, right? @EvanFrisch

Answer (score 0):

using powershell:

```
get-content <file path>|foreach-object{$_-replace'"',''}|set-content <file_destination>
```

Comment: While running the script it shows `get-content: command not found`. same for set-content also. @rtd5033

Comment: @RiteekSrivastava unfortunately this is a windows powershell snippet. what are you trying to run this in if you are using MacOS?